# (Julia) Quickly make a column-wise sum over an array

Tags: arrays, optimization, multidimensional-array, julia

I have an MxN array A of floats, and I would like to make the following operation:
For every column of A, count the number of elements which are smaller than some threshold (e.g. 0.5).

The fastest way for Julia to do this would be to initialise a result vector with zeros and then run through the array A column-wise and increment the result vector if needed. Doing this using for loops is easy, for instance

```
function count(A)
    (cols, rows) = size(A)
    result = fill(0, cols)
    for j in 1:rows
        for i in 1:cols
            result[i] += A[i,j] <= 0.5
        end
    end
end
```

This traverses A in the same order it is layout in memory and it allocates no unneeded extra space. However, I am unsure how to accomplish this using for instance the broadcasting operators .<=0.5, sum etc. One way to do it is

```
sum(A .<= 0.5, dims=1)
```

but this allocates new memory just to do the operations and is about 2-3 times slower than the count-function (I tested it for arrays up to 8000x8000). Is it possible to achieve the performance of the count-function but using only a few lines of code (like the second method)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A natural way for me to write your condition is:

```
count.(<=(0.5), eachcol(A))
```

or

```
vec(sum(<=(0.5), A, dims=1))
```

(the latter is a tad slower than the former but performs much less allocations, so probably the performance balance will depend on the dimensions of the matrix)

In general both should be reasonably fast and easy to read.

As a side note - your code performs count in rows not in columns. This is the way to correct it to perform counts in columns:

```
function count2(A)
    (rows, cols) = size(A)
    result = fill(0, cols)
    for i in 1:cols
        for j in 1:rows
            result[i] += A[j,i] <= 0.5
        end
    end
    result
end
```

Finally note that `sum(A .<= 0.5, dims=1)` performs a bit different operation as it returns a `Matrix` not a `Vector`.